# cublas batched gemm throw not supported error with large batch size

Tags: cuda, precision, cublas

I am calling the cublasGemmStridedBatchedEx() API. I have the first matrix proceeding with stride and the second one fixed. The program works well with small input but throws CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED error with a large batch size.

According to the [cublas documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-GemmStridedBatchedEx), this means the data type or algorithm is not supported. I can't see how increasing batch size changes the data type. I use the default heuristic GEMM algorithm.

I compiled the code with CUDA9.2 and ran it on a GTX 1050 card.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

#include "nvidia_helper/checkCudaErrors.h"

int UPPER_BOUND = 4096;

int main() {
    half* F4_re;
    half* X_split;
    float* result1;

    int M = 16;
    int B = 256*64;

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **) &F4_re, 4 * 4 * sizeof(half)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **) &X_split, M * 4 * B * 4 * sizeof(half)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **) &result1, M * 4 * B * 4 * sizeof(float)));

    F4_re[0] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[1] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[2] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[3] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[4] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[5] = 0.0f;
    F4_re[6] =-1.0f;
    F4_re[7] = 0.0f;
    F4_re[8] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[9] =-1.0f;
    F4_re[10] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[11] =-1.0f;
    F4_re[12] = 1.0f;
    F4_re[13] = 0.0f;
    F4_re[14] =-1.0f;
    F4_re[15] = 0.0f;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < M * 4 * B * 4; i++) {
       X_split[i] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX) * 2 * UPPER_BOUND - UPPER_BOUND;
    }

    cublasStatus_t status;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    float alpha = 1.0f, beta = 0.0f; 

    status = cublasCreate(&handle);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!! CUBLAS initialization error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    status = cublasSetMathMode(handle, CUBLAS_TENSOR_OP_MATH); // allow Tensor Core
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!! CUBLAS setting math mode error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    long long int stride = M * 4;

    status = cublasGemmStridedBatchedEx(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, M, 4, 4, &alpha, X_split,
             CUDA_R_16F, M, stride, F4_re, CUDA_R_16F, 4, 0, &beta, result1, CUDA_R_32F, M, stride, B * 4, CUDA_R_32F, CUBLAS_GEMM_DEFAULT);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!! CUBLAS kernel execution error: %d .\n", status);
        exit(1);
    }

    status = cublasDestroy(handle);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!! shutdown error (A)\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(F4_re));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(X_split));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(result1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [mcve], see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  What you have provided is not a complete example.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Description has been updated

Comment: @XiaoheCheng Please add information at what specific matrix sizes the code stops working. This batched API is designed for the use case of many small matrices (which would be inefficient to handle via classical BLAS API calls) and it *could* (speculation!) have a restriction on matrix size (possibly maximum dimension around 150-200) that was inadvertently omitted from the documentation.

Comment: @talonmies I followed the description here: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cublas-strided-batched-matrix-multiply/. You can search 'more optimizations' to locate the related content. And it works well if the batch size changes from B * 4 to B in the above code

Comment: according to my testing, the supplied code will fail (return cublas error code 15 - `CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`) with the given matrix dimensions if the batch count passed to `cublasGemmStridedBatchedEx` is 65535 or greater. To be clear, my observation: 65536 fails, 65535 fails, 65534 passes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Seems like a bug should be filed. Either the limitation exists by design, in which case tjis is a documentation bug, or the limitation is unintentional, in which case it's an implementation bug.

Comment: I've already filed an internal bug at NVIDIA.  I don't have any further information at this time.

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be rectified in the CUBLAS patch release that was just issued and is available [here](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda)

Look for this patch:

> Patch 1 (Released Aug 6, 2018)

This is a patch that must be installed on top of a proper CUDA 9.2.148 install.

First you must install CUDA 9.2.148.  Then install the patch.